# Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: angularjs, github, command-prompt, visual-studio-2015

I have some problems.I have install dnu restore by command prompt. dnu is install successful but when I have run the application the issues are occurred given like this title.So what can I do solved this problems.Please help me step by step .